# Execute system commands in postgresql

Tags: c, postgresql, shell, unix, rdbms

My requirement is to execute a system command like (ls) or C program when a trigger executes. Is there any way to create a trigger function to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can write trigger functions [Python](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpython.html), [Perl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plperl.html) or [Tcl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/pltcl.html), and provided that you use the ["untrusted"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plperl-trusted.html) version of the language, any of these can be used to execute arbitrary shell commands. The shell will be run under the same user as the Postgres server process (typically "postgres"), so you will need to set permissions accordingly.

For example, after running `CREATE EXTENSION plpythonu`, you can write a trigger function using `LANGUAGE plpythonu`, and run commands by calling e.g. [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system).

Take care with any commands which modify the system, as these changes are not tied to your database transaction (so you would need to find your own way of dealing with concurrent writes, transaction rollbacks, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick exampe of how you can achieve this in PG15 on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-plpython3-15

CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reboot_server(version text) RETURNS text AS $BODY$
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(f"/usr/lib/postgresql/{version}/bin/pg_ctl restart -D /var/lib/postgresql/{version}/main",shell=True)
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;

select * from reboot_server('15')
```

In this case, i'm restarting specified instance of postgres.